# How do I use public keys vs. private key for StrongName?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cryptography, assemblies, strongname

What is the difference between public key and private key usage for .snk files?

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Understand the difference between private key and public key in terms of usage.

Answer (score 1):

You use the:

- private key to sign the assembly;
- public key to validate the signature (on the assembly);

Both are mathematically related, read about RSA public key cryptography for details.

As such you need to protect the private key if you want to ensure no one else can produce a signed assembly using the same public key token as yourself.

note: the public key token is a reduced version (part of the SHA1 digest) of your public key (which would be too long to show in most scenarios).